# MYSQL - Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '' on SELECT query

Tags: mysql, select, double, truncated

We have a search facility on our website that returns products and articles related to the search term in 2 separate queries.

To improve accuracy we've added a keyword table so we can link specific search terms to a product or article.

Table structure is:

| id | product | helpid | keyword |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | prod1 |  | car |
| 2 | prod2 |  | van |
| 3 |  | 10 | car |
| 4 | prod3 |  | car |
| 5 |  | 12 | van |

So a search term can be linked to a product or help article.

On the admin side we have a page that lists the most recently added keywords, with a count of how many products and articles they link to.

I tried this query, but the counts were incorrect as they included NULL or blank rows:

```
SELECT MAX(id) as maxid, keyword, 
COUNT(product) AS prodcount, COUNT(helpid) AS helpcount 
FROM keyword_table 
GROUP BY keyword 
ORDER BY maxid DESC 
LIMIT 40
```

So I switched to conditional SUM instead of COUNT:

```
SELECT MAX(id) as maxid, keyword, 
SUM(if(product != '', 1, 0)) AS prodcount, SUM(if(helpid != '', 1, 0)) AS helpcount 
FROM keyword_table 
GROUP BY keyword 
ORDER BY maxid DESC
LIMIT 40
```

This appears to give the correct values, but with this warning:

> Warning: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: ''

Every article I've found on that error relates to UPDATE queries, not SELECT.

Please does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

you should filter your results with a WHERE, doing it with an IF is what give you warnings most probably.

Try it like this if the following brings the same results(with nulls) change IS NOT NULL to  != ''  and try agian ..

```
SELECT MAX(id) as maxid, keyword, 
COUNT(product) AS prodcount, COUNT(helpid) AS helpcount 
FROM keyword_table 
WHERE product IS NOT NULL OR helpid IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY keyword 
ORDER BY maxid 
DESC LIMIT 40
```

Comment: Demeteor - One or other of product and helpid will always be not null, so that doubles up on the count.

I need to only count product if product is not empty/null, and ditto for helpid